# How to return multiple 0 value from multiple columns into 1 row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
Name   Apple Banana Cherry Lemon Lime
Alice   0     3      1      0     1 
John    1     0      0      2     0
```

and now I want the return value to be:

```
Name  Apple Lemon
Alice 0     0
```

or

```
Name Banana Cherry Lime
John 0      0      0
```

How can I get the 0 value for multiple columns in this case? The actual database has about 100 columns so I would like to find a way solve this issue as well

Comment: You mean 0, not null, right? I'd query with a simple `SELECT` statement, listing all the column names (don't use "*") and when you loop over the result set you can work with the fields that contain a 0.

Comment: The actual database has ~100 columns and it is really time consuming to type all the name down. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: What do you mean "type all the name down"?  Remember that the rows in an SQL query always have the same number of columns.  Are you calling this from a programming language?  It would be easy to read every row, then just extract the zero columns for that row and save or print them.

Comment: This looks like either an XY-problem or a really bad schema design; what you essentially need is a query constructed dynamically to include only the relevant columns, and of course can only ever return a single row (or at least only rows where *name* has the same columns in common for zero values). This is horrible, most likely your columns should be normalised as rows.

Comment: Sound alike you have a denormalised design and you shouldn't have 1 column per fruit, but a column for the name of the fruit and a column for the value/number. There the answer would be as trivial as `WHERE Number = 0`.

Comment: You really need to sort out that table design, it's completely denormalized.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reconsider your desired output.  This would require Dynamic SQL and would only make sense for a single row ( or identical zeros)

Here is an option that will UNPIVOT your 100+ columns without using Dynamic SQL and return a nice normalized structure  ... dare I say EAV  :)

**Example**

```
Select A.[Name]
      ,B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select [item] = try_convert(varchar(25),[key])
                       ,[value]  = try_convert(int,Value)
                 From OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                 Where [key] not in ('Name','OtherColumns','ToExclude')
                   and try_convert(int,Value)=0
              ) B
```

**Results**

```
Name    item    value
Alice   Apple   0
Alice   Lemon   0
John    Banana  0
John    Cherry  0
John    Lime    0
```

**On second thought**, another option is `string_agg()`

```
Select A.[Name]
      ,B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select [ZeroCols]  = string_agg([key],',')
                 From OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                 Where [key] not in ('Name','OtherColumns','ToExclude')
                   and try_convert(int,Value)=0
              ) B
```

**Results**

```
Name    ZeroCols
Alice   Apple,Lemon
John    Banana,Cherry,Lime
```